# Restart to see changes? Cherokee + uWSGI + Django/Pinax + Virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv, pinax, cherokee, uwsgi

I'm having some trouble with Cherokee + uWSGI picking up on code changes to .py files in my django app.  Even using

`find -name "*.pyc" -delete`

...seems to have no effect.

Changes are noticed instantly, on refresh, when running the same code base under django runserver

How do I force restart and reliably see changes under Cherokee + uWSGI + Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django development server picks up on code changes, but this is not a feature you'd want in a production server. You need to restart your Python processes, monitored by uwsgi, in order to run your latest code. On FreeBSD with uwsgi from ports, you can do:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/uwsgi restart
```

More info in the [uwsgi manual](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki).

Answer (score 9):

In your `uwsgi.xml` you could add `<touch-reload>/path/to/file</touch-reload>`.

When you run `touch /path/to/file` your changes should be loaded.